# Basic help on arrays in C

Tags: c

I can't display correctly my arrays, I don't understand what the problem is.

Here is my code :

```
int increment = 1;
int para_1_courant = 10;
int para_2_courant = 4;
int para_1_min = 5;
int para_1_max = 10;

int para_2_min = 1;
int para_2_max = 4;

int tab_para_automate[2][2] = {{0}};
int tab_para_application[1][3] = {{0}};

tab_para_automate[0][0] = para_1_min;
tab_para_automate[0][1] = para_1_max;
tab_para_automate[1][0] = para_2_min;
tab_para_automate[1][1] = para_2_max;
printf("coucou1");

tab_para_application[0][0] = para_1_courant;
tab_para_application[0][1] = para_2_courant;
tab_para_application[0][2] = increment;
printf("coucou2\n");
int k,l;

for (k=0 ; k<1 ; k++)
{
    for (l=0 ; l<1 ; l++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", tab_para_automate[k][l]);
    }
}
```

In output I only get this : "coucou1", "coucou2", 5

Comment: Whats the problem you are having?

Comment: `k<1` -> `k<2`, same for `l`.

Comment: `l < 1` if your `l` starts at 0, it will only pass one time in your loop

Comment: My loops are supposed to display all the content of the array "tab_para_automate", but in output i only get one value

Comment: Damn i'm so stupid, i used k<2 it solved the problem aha

Answer (score 2):

The loop:

```
for (k=0 ; k<1 ; k++)
```

goes until `k < 1`, so just for `k = 0`, and similarly it goes for `l = 0`, so you get just one iteration to display the element at `tab_para_automate[0][0]`.

You should make both loops condition `< 2` if you wnat to show all elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (k=0 ; k<2 ; k++)
{
  for (l=0 ; l<2 ; l++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", tab_para_automate[k][l]);
  }
}
```

You mistyped size of matrix

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the code on this way to take care about index 1

```
for (k=0 ; k<=1 ; k++)
{
    for (l=0 ; l<=1 ; l++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", tab_para_automate[k][l]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In c it is not customary to use `<=` for the upperbound (though it is not wrong)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie as far as I remember in ANSI C this `<=` is perfectly fine :)

Comment: As I say, "though it is not wrong". Note that arrays go from 0..n-1, so it is customary to write 
`for (i=0; i<n;...` instead of `for (i=0; i<=n-1;...`

Comment: Right, @PaulOgilvie. My intention was to demonstrate one more approach to the problem